# How to display record in gridview using pageload event in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

How to display record in gridview using pageload event in vb.net ?

i wanna use two SqlDatasource1 and sqldatasource 2 to display record in single gridview1

SqlDatasource1 will display all records from tabel where as SqlDatasource will be used to display particuar record search in table 1 but how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to display all records from a table besides the records that belong to a particaúlar filter on that table. How do you want do make clear what is the filtered and what the unfiltered part?

You could use [UNION ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to combine two resultsets together. You could also add a column that contains a boolean if it belongs to the filtered set. On this way you would be able to add different [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx)es to the rows according to this column value from [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) in Codebehind.

For example:

```
SELECT Foo.*,0 AS IsFiltered FROM Foo
UNION ALL 
SELECT Foo.*,1 AS IsFiltered FROM Foo
where Name like 's%
```

You only need one SQL-Datasource on this way.

To set a different CssClass for the filtered records:

```
 Private Sub GridRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
     If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
         Dim row As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
         Dim isFiltered As Boolean = CType(row("IsFiltered"), Boolean)
         If isFiltered Then e.Row.CssClass = "FilteredRecords"
     End If
 End Sub
```

'